# MSMQ Save Failed MessageBody to Text File

Tags: c#, stream, msmq

I'm writing a Windows Service to listen and process messages from MSMQ. The listener has various error handling steps, but if all else fails, I want to save the body of the message to a text file so that I can look at it. However, I can't seem to extract the content of my messages when this condition is hit. The following code is a simple representation of the sections in question, and it always produces an empty text file even though I know the message I'm testing with is not empty. HOWEVER, if I comment-out the initial attempt to deserialize the XML, the fail safe does work and produces a text file with the message body. So I think the problem is something to do with how the deserialization attempt leaves the underlying Stream? Just to clarify, when the message contains valid XML that CAN be deserialized, the service all works fine and the fail-safe never comes into action.

```
        MyClass myClass = null;

        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));

            // Comment the following out and the fail safe works
            // Let this run and fail and the text file below is always empty
            myClass = (MyClass)serializer.Deserialize(m.BodyStream);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        if (myClass == null)
        {
            string filePath = @"D:\path\file.txt";

            m.Formatter = new ActiveXMessageFormatter();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(m.BodyStream);

            File.WriteAllText(filePath, reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
```

Comment: I think you need to use System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode & System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode.  Html won't except certain special characters : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this isn't a web page, so surely HTML isn't relevant here? I appreciate XML is a mark-up language like HTML, but would special characters really stop it being written to a text file?

Comment: Are you sure your service isn't isn't html?  A "messageBody" is usually a email message that is html.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely nothing to do with emails or HTML - I'm using MSMQ to queue a message between applications.

Comment: I knew I was correct.  See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms699792(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @jdweng - thanks again, but it's really not an email! Yes, the messages can be sent over the http protocol, but it doesn't mean they are HTML either. Thanks for trying to help though, I appreciate it.

Comment: All http are composed of HTML.  What you meant is not all messages are http.  MSMQ is messaging and does use http.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the formatter you are using:

For windows binary messages:

```
File.WriteAllText(<path>, (new UTF8Encoding()).GetString((byte[])msg.Body)); // for binary
```

For XML messages try this:

```
msg.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new String[] { "System.String, mscorlib" });
var text = msg.Body.ToString(); 
// write to file..
```

For neither binary or XML, use the native formatter:

```
msg.Formatter = new ActiveXMessageFormatter();
reader = new StreamReader(msg.BodyStream);
msgBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
// write to file..
```

Comment: Tom : See my last response above.

Comment: @jdweng - Cool! Though how do you know this is a HTTP message?

Comment: Thank you! I tried that but it gives the following exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot deserialize the message passed as an argument. Cannot recognize the serialization format.
at System.Messaging.BinaryMessageFormatter.Read(Message message)
at System.Messaging.Message.get_Body()

Comment: Tried again using the formatter you added, but it now gives the following exception: System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing ...the message I am testing with doesn't contain valid XML but that's the point, this is supposed to be my fail-safe to capture the details of invalid message so I can review and investigate. I don't really want to serialise it at all, I just want to write the content out to a text file, whatever it is. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Are you sending the messages via System.Messaging?

Comment: Because all email message bodies are http.  But like usual it wasn't very clear on the MSDN website and had to search awhile.

Comment: That's correct - using System.Messaging. Everything works great when the message is well formed with valid XML, I'm just trying to build in some fail safes in case the message is invalid or gets corrupt. I want to be able to see what was sent and manually edit/ditch/requeue it where necessary.

Comment: Thanks @tomredfern - I tried with the ActiveX formatter, but it still produces a blank file. I think the problem is something to do with how my original attempt to deserialise the body to XML leaves the underlying stream. If I comment out the attempt to deserialize the body and let it drop right through to the fail-safe, then it works perfectly and produces the text file as I want it to. So I think the actual issue must be something to do with closing/resetting the Stream? I might have to modify the original question with more details. Thanks for your help.